# Waiting for DRQ on ATA driver loops for infinity

Tags: c, io, operating-system, osdev, gdt

i have written a super simple os and i decided to start using grub to boot it, so i started a new projected and im getting my old kernel functions to the new kernel and the ATA driver is not working stuck when i wait for DRQ

```
void ATA_wait_DRQ() // Wait fot drq to be 1
{
    while (!(insb(0x1F7) & STATUS_RDY))
        ;
}
```

and the function to read the sector

```
int disk_read_sector(int lba, void *buf)
{
    ATA_wait_BSY();
    print("f1");
    ATA_wait_DRQ(); // estes dois nao estavam aqui antes pus so pq no write tive de por
    print("f2");

    lba = lba + OS_SECTORS + HEADER_SECTORS;
    outb(0x1F6, (lba >> 24) | 0xE0);
    outb(0x1F2, 1);
    outb(0x1F3, (unsigned char)(lba & 0xff));
    outb(0x1F4, (unsigned char)(lba >> 8));
    outb(0x1F5, (unsigned char)(lba >> 16));
    outb(0x1F7, 0x20);

    unsigned short *ptr = (unsigned short *)buf;

    ATA_wait_BSY();
    ATA_wait_DRQ();

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        *ptr = insw(0x1F0);
        ptr++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

this used to work on my old bootloader so i think is something related to it
the idt is also from the old bootloader and de gdt is the same as nanobyte used [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5LbXClJhxcs) so im really lost
the interrupts are working fine, div 0 is good keyboard input also, my unique current problem

i added this function

```
void checkPort()
{
    char a = insb(0x1F7);
    a = a + 48;
    write_char_pos(5, 5, a, 0x00ff00);
    if (a == '0')
    {
        char b = insb(0x1F1);
        b = b + 48;
        write_char_pos(6, 6, a, 0x00ff00);
    }
}
```

and it wrote on pos 5,5 the 0 so i think im getting an error and on line 6,6 also a 0

Comment: are you running this in a virtual machine? it may have debugging abilities, or you may be able to look at the source code. [Here on page 22](https://ceunican.github.io/aos/36.IO_Devices.pdf) I found the 0x1F7 and 0x1F1 registers. What value does 0x1F7 get stuck on?

Comment: Are you sure that it's looping forever and not crashed because it got an interrupt that wasn't handled properly?

Comment: so... it was on the emulator... always try things on other emulators guys :D u had -cdrom on qemu startup.. it always worked for me but this time i didnt :D